# What's the best way to parse this JSON in dotnet core?

Tags: json, serialization, .net-core

I have a json file similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "records": [
      {
        "originalEventTimestamp": "2020-10-21T17:18:02.5353507Z",
        "time": "2020-10-21T17:18:02.5359120Z",
        "properties": {
          "audit_schema_version": 1,
          "event_id": "059B9CA8-29EA-4CC4-AC72-7FAD567C09AD"
        }
      },
      {
        "originalEventTimestamp": "2020-10-21T17:18:18.5820720Z",
        "time": "2020-10-21T17:18:18.5828543Z",
        "properties": {
          "audit_schema_version": 1,
          "event_id": "00B6B0F4-8CD0-49E2-BE7F-1392BC0C6E05"
        }
      }
    ],
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2020-10-21T17:23:12.7628776Z",
    "PartitionId": 1,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2020-10-21T17:20:35.8420000Z"
  }
]
```

I've been following a JSON tutorial that led me down this path:

```
JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Data.Body.ToArray()));
JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
JsonElement recordsElement = root.GetProperty("records");

foreach (JsonElement record in recordsElement.EnumerateArray())
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tHello World - number 2a:{0}", record.ToString());
                 
    if (record.TryGetProperty("audit_schema_version", out JsonElement audit_schema_version))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tHello World - number 3:{0}", audit_schema_version.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tHello World - number 4, no audit_schema_version");
    }
}
```

I'm using System.Text.Json and System.Text.Json.Serialization. How can I parse this and get to the audit_schema_version value?

Comment: Any reason to use dynamic queries? Can't you just use classes?

Comment: No, no reason to use dynamic queries, learning on the fly, classes will work also.

Comment: Then all you need is https://json2csharp.com/ (or a similar tool, if you don't like that one)

Comment: You should access `properties` token first, then get `audit_schema_version` value

Comment: Why not simply use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) for serialization. I think currently ```System.Text``` is not supporting Dictionaries.